# Adding icons to amCharts Tooltips

Tags: javascript, css, html, amcharts

I've created a simple chart using amCharts Javascript library. It has a simple **tooltip** which is in charge of showing each bar's value (Points of the user).

Here is what I'm talking about:

[image: Image can't be loaded!]

Now I want to go further and display a little image or icon just behind each value in the tooltip. Something like this one:

[image]

Here is the link which explains how we can handle creating [Tooltips with rich HTML content](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/tooltips-with-rich-html-content/).

Unfortunately, I can't handle this because of its complexity and my low experience. But I'm sure there should be a way to archive this...

Here is My Javascript code:

```
// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
var myVar = { 
    Red: "#f72c69",
    Normal: "#6887cc",
};

var userA_points = 22;
var userB_points = 20;
var userC_points = 6;
var members_points = 12;
var max_points = Math. max(userA_points, userB_points, userC_points, members_points);
var maxPlus = (max_points + 10)
maxPlus = Math.min(200, Math.max(0, maxPlus));
console.log(maxPlus);

if(userA_points < members_points){
    var colorCompare = myVar.Red
} else {
    var colorCompare = myVar.Normal
}


// Add data
chart.data = [{
    "name": "Damon",
    "points": userA_points,
    "color": "#5479f2",
    "bullet": "https://www.scripturaengage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Profile-Picture-Koen-VanGeert-circle-ScripturaEngage.png",
    "bullet2": "Diamonds.png"
}, {
    "name": "filip",
    "points": userB_points,
    "color": "#5479f2",
    "bullet": "https://www.scripturaengage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Profile-Picture-Pauline-Suy-circle-ScripturaEngage.png",
    "bullet2": "Diamonds.png"
}, {
    "name": "Patrick",
    "points": userC_points,
    "color": "#5479f2",
    "bullet": "https://www.scripturaengage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Profile-Picture-Pauline-Suy-circle-ScripturaEngage.png",
    "bullet2": "Diamonds.png"
}, {
    "name": "All Members",
    "points": members_points,
    "color": colorCompare,
    "bullet": "Members.png",
    "bullet2": "Diamonds.png"
}];

// Create axes
var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "name";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;
categoryAxis.renderer.inside = true;
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.fill = am4core.color("#fff");
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.fontSize = 20;

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.strokeDasharray = "4,4";
valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = false;
valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.fontSize = 15;
valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.fontWeight = "800";

valueAxis.min = 0;
valueAxis.max = maxPlus;
valueAxis.strictMinMax = true;  
valueAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 25;

// Do not crop bullets
chart.maskBullets = false;

// Remove padding
chart.paddingBottom = 0;
chart.paddingTop = 50;
// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "points";
series.dataFields.categoryX = "name";
series.columns.template.propertyFields.fill = "color";
series.columns.template.propertyFields.stroke = "color";
series.columns.template.column.cornerRadiusTopLeft = 25;
series.columns.template.column.cornerRadiusTopRight = 25;
series.columns.template.tooltipText = "{categoryX}: [bold]{valueY}[/b]";


// Add bullets
var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.Bullet());
var image = bullet.createChild(am4core.Image);
image.width = 120;
image.height = 120;
image.horizontalCenter = "middle";
image.verticalCenter = "bottom";
image.dy = 70;
image.y = am4core.percent(100);
image.propertyFields.href = "bullet";
image.tooltipText = series.columns.template.tooltipText;
image.propertyFields.fill = "color";
image.filters.push(new am4core.DropShadowFilter());

// Add bullets
var bullet2 = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.Bullet());
var image = bullet2.createChild(am4core.Image);
image.width = 60;
image.height = 60;
image.horizontalCenter = "middle";
image.verticalCenter = "bottom";
image.dy = 60;
image.dx = 50;
image.y = am4core.percent(100);
image.propertyFields.href = "bullet2";
image.tooltipText = series.columns.template.tooltipText;
image.propertyFields.fill = "color";
image.filters.push(new am4core.DropShadowFilter());
```

HTML Code :

```
<!-- Resources -->
<script language="JavaScript" src="amcharts4/core.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="amcharts4/charts.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="amcharts4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
  <script src="Script.js"></script>
```

CSS Code:

```
#chartdiv {
  width: 1500px;
  height: 750px;
}

body {  
    margin: 90 100 100 20;
    background-color: transparent;
    overflow:hidden;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  font-weight: 800;
  src: url(helveticaneue-ultrathin.woff);   
 }
```

Any solution is appreciated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `tooltipHTML` instead of `tooltipText`. There you can use HTML to design your tooltips. To add an image simply use the `<img>` tag:

```
series.columns.template.tooltipHTML = "<img src='your-image.png' style='vertical-align:bottom; margin-right: 10px; width:21px; height:21px;'><span style='font-size:14px; color:#000000;'><b>POINTS {valueY.value}</b></span><br><img src='your-image.png' style='vertical-align:bottom; margin-right: 10px; width:21px; height:21px;'><span style='font-size:14px; color:#000000;'><b>Game overs: {gameOvers}</b></span>";
```

I created a [code pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zbYmLR) as reference, but most of the images don't work there.

Comment: Another Brilliant Answer... You're Awesome Samuel P